# help with php and variables

Tags: php

script example can be found at http://panelbackup.com/e.php

how can I get these random numbers appended to a url prior to it being served by the script? So far the url is loading, and I have a variable for generating the random number, but I am having trouble piecing them together to both be called together. You can see from loading the page that the page is loaded, and the random number string is printed to the page, but I am needing it appended to the url prior to serving it. Here is the code:

```
<?php
$c=print rand(1111, 9999);
$a=fopen('http://test.com','');
$b = stream_get_contents($a);
echo $b;
fclose($a);
```

So technically, I am wanting this to pull url.com/page#### when the page is loaded, and when refreshed, load url.com/page####, with the #### being another set of randoms. Don't need any slashes, etc. only url and then the numbers concatenated to the end. How would I call both variable $a and $c together? (I may also have this syntax wrong, if so, please clarify/help)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$c = rand(1111, 9999);
$a = fopen('http://test.com/' . $c, 'r');
$b = stream_get_contents($a);
echo $b;
fclose($a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
$a=fopen('http://test.com','');
```

To:

```
$a=fopen('http://test.com/page'.$c,'r');
```

Or use `file_get_contents()` instead:

```
$a = file_get_contents('http://test.com/page'.$c);
```

You might also want to append a `?` if you're planning on using the random numbers the way I think you are, then just change `/page` to `/page?`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$c=rand(1111, 9999);
$a=file_get_contents ("http://test.com/page$c");
echo $a; // http://test.com/page1111
```

you were trying to print the values of functions to variables, you can directly assign them. I would not recommend fopen() for URLs as this has to be explicitly enabled in php.ini